# How to schedule DLRS in Salesforce

Tags: dlrs

I'm looking for a document (or a vidéo) which describes in detailed steps how to schedule a full calculation of a declarative lookup summary. I don't need to calculate in real-time.

There are 2 tabs calculate job and schedule item, but I don't know how to fill the fields. There is no date or hours in these forms.

Comment: I'm looking for a document (or a vidéo)...did you try searching the [H&T portal](https://help.salesforce.com/) or anywhere else? Please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 4):

You need to first click on **Manage Lookup rollup Summaries** tab and then select the lookup rollup summary which you want to schedule.

Afterwards, you need to click on the "Schedule Calculate" button.

After clicking, a new page will open which looks like this:

[image]

Here, you need to fill the schedule details and then click on "Schedule Recurring Calculate Job", and that's it!

You have scheduled the DLRS in Salesforce